# A blank in the URI works in production but fails in development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webserver, uri, webrick

I have the following code which works in production:

```
 redirect_to "/mycontroller/index.html#&panel1-2?error=Invalid Member ID and/or Date of Birth"
```

In development(using Webrick), I am getting the following error message:

```
ERROR URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/index.html#&panel1-2?error=Invalid Member ID and/or Date of Birth
```

But if I copy and paste the supposedly bad URI in my browser address bar, it works!

I have tried various combinations of the error message text, and the spaces between words is causing it. I can make it work by using URI.escape or some other technique to escape the spaces, but then I would have to change hundreds of such occurrences in code which is working fine.

Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown below, your URI is actually invalid. You can't have unescaped spaces in your URI.

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > require 'URI'                                                                                                                             => true
1.9.3p194 :002 > URI.parse('http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/index.html#&panel1-2?error=Invalid Member ID and/or Date of Birth')
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/index.html#&panel1-2?error=Invalid Member ID and/or Date of Birth
    from /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:176:in `split'
    from /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:211:in `parse'
    from /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/uri/common.rb:747:in `parse'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/ccashwell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

You should `escape` the URI:

```
1.9.3p194 :003 > URI.escape('http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/index.html#&panel1-2?error=Invalid Member ID and/or Date of Birth')
 => "http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/index.html%23&panel1-2?error=Invalid%20Member%20ID%20and/or%20Date%20of%20Birth"
```

Then you can `redirect_to` the escaped URI:

```
redirect_to URI.escape('http://localhost:3000/mycontroller/index.html#&panel1-2?error=Invalid Member ID and/or Date of Birth')
```

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are usually replaced with `%20` for urls.  Most web browsers will automatically replace this for you, so this explains why the browser can go to the site.  Just use `%20` in place of your spaces and you should be all set.

Comment: With %20 the url would be /mycontroller/index.html#&panel1-2?error=Invalid%20Member%20ID%20and/or%20Date%20of%20Birth

Comment: that is exactly what I am trying to avoid. This is a large site in production, and this works as is. I am trying to find out what is making it work in prod so I can duplicate that in dev.